# How to change macro function argument expansion ordering?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#define TRACE_MACRO(EnterText) \
class CTrace \
{ \
public: \
CTrace() \
{ \
std::cout << EnterText;  \
} \
private:\
};

#define DO_TRACE TRACE_MACRO("[ENTER] " __FUNCTION__ "\r\n") CTrace trace

static void test()
{
    DO_TRACE;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    DO_TRACE;
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[ENTER] main::CTrace::CTrace
[ENTER] test::CTrace::CTrace
```

How can I write the macro such that `__FUNCTION__` is expanded first so that the output becomes:

```
[ENTER] main
[ENTER] test
```

I attempted to create a sub macro called DO_TRACE2 that forwards the arguments, but this results in the same output.

If this isn't possible then what about a macro that will compile time substring the text to strip off the CTrace::CTrace part of the string?

Edit: Note that I don't want to pass a pointer to a compile time string to this class, I want the call to std::cout to appear as if I had actually manually wrote std::cout << "main";

Comment: is it necessary to define a whole new class in the macro def?

Comment: According to C99 `__FUNCTION__` is not a macro, the preprocessor does not understand the concept of the "current function" because it doesn't know anything about C++ syntax or scope, so cannot know the function's name.

Comment: @Jimmy no, I just wanted the call to std::cout to be using const static compile time strings rather than a pointer to a compile time string, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but here's a simple rearrangement that might work:

```
#define TRACE_MACRO \
class CTrace \
{ \
public: \
CTrace(const char* text) \
{ \
std::cout << text;  \
} \
private:\
};

#define DO_TRACE TRACE_MACRO CTrace trace("[ENTER] " __FUNCTION__ "\r\n")
```

Comment: This works but I dont want to be passing a pointer to the compile time string, I want the call to std::cout using the the compile time string itself. I'll update the question to make this clear

Comment: Why?  What's your higher-level goal here that prevents you from using this working solution?

Comment: The reason is to avoid static analysis tool warning about passing a const char* to a format string function. Thus if I can use a macro to give it a string literal then this warning will go away. Only snag is FUNCTION not working as expected.

Comment: Where is there a format string being used here?  Is this not your actual code?  Are you actually using printf() and need to do special things to support that, but haven't told us?

Comment: std::cout would be a call to _vscwprintf as the string is passed down to another logging function that writes it to disk

Comment: The string will be compiled into your binary regardless - all the macro does is rewrite the code before submitting to the compiler

Comment: If I decompile the above code this isn't true as its stored in a pointer first - but either way the static analysis tool will complain because it sees a const char* being passed in

Comment: @paulm: OK, so what you should do is to call `printf("%s", text);`.  Then, problem solved.  Or even better, use `fputs()` or similar to avoid parsing a format string at all.

Comment: But this would mean copying the string twice, and there are over 10,000 instances of this

Comment: Where would this extra "copy" occur exactly?  Anyway as I said you should stop using printf() to write known strings with no format specifiers in.

Comment: There is an overload which logs arguments which does require _vscwprintf, so in that instance I guess there is no solution?

Comment: The warning is caused because the string isn't a literal though, so that will probably cause more warnings :)

Comment: So you're trying to make your code as complicated as possible... just to satisfy a static analysis tool? LOL!

Comment: I essentially went for the printf("%s", text); option. @Lightness Races in Orbit I was trying to silence the warning and make it more efficient by avoiding the intermediate pointer to constant static string and use the string directly in place.

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy asked

> is it necessary to define a whole new class in the macro def?

And you replied:

> @Jimmy no, I just wanted the call to std::cout to be using const
>   static compile time strings rather than a pointer to a compile time
>   string, if that makes sense.

So why not just drop the class:

```
#define DO_TRACE std::cout << "[ENTER] " << __FUNCTION__ << "\r\n"
```

This will output:

```
[ENTER] main 
[ENTER] test
```

and uses the const static compile time string....

I probably missed something, just tell me, I'll delete this post....

By the way, I compiled the code from your post using GNU GCC version 4.8.1 from http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php. It outputs

```
[ENTER] CTrace 
[ENTER] CTrace
```

So looks like FUNCTION macro is resolved differenetly by compilers...